# Angular-deckgrid and bindonce

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a way of using [angular-bindonce](https://github.com/pasvaz/bindonce) together with [angular-deckgrid](https://github.com/akoenig/angular-deckgrid), without making a custom changes to both plugins.

My goal is to make a grid-view which will render about 1000 images in it. Without bindonce it starts lagging at about 200 images, because of the ng-watches.

If there a solution on this or I should make my own custom directive?

I figured out that the fastest way to do this will be if I edit [a fork of angular-deckgrid](https://github.com/akoenig/angular-deckgrid/blob/master/angular-deckgrid.js) and import a bindonce directive at the template var at lines 57-59. What do you think about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a custom directive, which has just 1 watch (model) and it's rerendering the html using pure javascript.